# what is the proper way for an azure admin to notify a new azure user that their new user account has been created?

Tags: azure

I need to migrate my company to Azure.  I created a new Azure instance via my work email for my company.  I went through the standard "Add User" routine to add the owner of the company to Azure as a user with a role of "Global Administrator."  Now that I've added the owner to Azure, what is the proper way to notify him that I've added him as a user in Azure?  I entered the following value into the "User Name" input when creating his Azure user:

mike@{myemailname}{myemaildomain}.onmicrosoft.com

The domain above was hard-coded based on the Azure instance that I was currently logged into.  He wouldn't be aware of receiving an email at that address because he had no previous knowledge of this Azure instance.  I reviewed his user profile after I created it and I hadn't previously entered his email address upon account creation because it wasn't a required field.

So does Azure have some type of "Notify User of New Account" button or should this type of notification be generated through some type of "Change Password" button which will send an email to the user to initiate the initial login process?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> **Note** that : There is no built-in "Notify User of New Account" or "Change Password" buttons exist in Azure that would instantly contact the user. The account owner or administrator is responsible for alerting the user, giving them login information, and providing instructions on how to access and utilize Azure.

When you create a user using Add User, New user in Azure AD gets created and `.onmicrosoft.com` is added to all user's UPN by default in Azure AD.

As a **workaround**, you can invite the user instead of creating users like below:

> If you want to invite the user with existing Email account, you can use Invite User feature.

[image]

Once the user is invited, the user gets the mail to Accept invitation like below:

[image]

When the user clicks Accept invitation, the **consent screen** will appear like below:

[image]

After consenting the user will be added as the **Guest** in the Azure Active Directory:

[image]

You can change the **UserType** by editing the properties as **`Member`**:

[image]

The user is updated as **Member** like below:

[image]

If the above workaround doesn't meet your requirement, then you have manually inform users of New Account.

You can perform Bulk operations while inviting the Guest Users.